# im making a discord bot for the first time in discord js and my test command wont work

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

This is "my code" and the command doesn't work. tried following a YouTube tutorial. this is my first time trying to do something like this. all my code experience comes from simple python code. so if you have any vids that explains this pls send

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permissions, Message } = require(`discord.js`);

const prefix = '>';

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        32767
    ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("botong is online!")

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: 'online',
        activity: {
            name: 'status',
            type: 'ActivityType.Playing'
        }
    });
});

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);

    //message array

    const messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    const argument = messageArray.slice(1);
    const cmd = messageArray[0];

    //commands

    //test commands

    if (commands === 'test') {
        message.channel.send("Bot is working!")
    }

})

client.login("MY TOKEN");
```

tried to run this and nothing happened, it should send a message in my discord server saying "Bot is Working"

Answer (score 0):

> so if you have any vids that explains this pls send

Here's an article from Codeacademy which explains how to create a simple Discord bot. https://www.codecademy.com/article/christine_yang/build-a-discord-bot-with-node-js

Reason why your test message doesn't appear: the message never gets sent because you haven't defined `commands` so it can obviously never be `'test'`.

```
if (commands === 'test') {
message.channel.send("Bot is working!")
}
```

Edit: Here's a code sample from the article which sends message to the channel each time someone sends "Hello" there.

```
client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
// You can view the msg object here with console.log(msg)
 if (msg.content === 'Hello') {
   msg.reply(`Hello ${msg.author.username}`);
 }
});
```